# Flex- Getting the 1st Visible element in a List

Tags: apache-flex, scroll

I have a list in Spark that is displayed.
As we scroll the list, is there a way to know the 1st element among the elements that are currently visible after scrolling?
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The List class encapsulates a [DataGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGroup.html).
This DataGroup has a method called [getItemIndicesInView()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGroup.html#getItemIndicesInView%28%29).

So to find the first visible item do:

```
var firstVisibleIndex:int = myList.dataGroup.getItemIndicesInView()[0];
trace(myDataProvider.getItemAt(firstVisibleIndex));
```

Comment: Ya, it helped.
Thanks a lot! :)